# How to have an Iterator for a Dictionary?

Tags: c#

I have a Class that uses a dictionary to store some data.

But I want to hide that implementation detail from the outside, to iterate all my data I would like to send an iterator to the ouside of my class

how can I do this?

Comment: Copy all values(references) into a simple (typed) list and return that list?

Comment: What you want your iterator to return? What the outside code will iterate over?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, string>> Foo()
{
    var implementationDetail = new Dictionary<int, string>
    {
        { 1, "foo" },
        { 2, "bar" },
    };

    return implementationDetail;
}
```

Comment: If you want to _totally_ hide the fact that you are using a dictionary, you can also return `implementationDetail.Cast<KeyValuePair<int, string>>()`, which will also prevent stuff like `((Dictionary<int, string>)obj.Foo()).Add(...)` ;)

Answer (score 2):

You may call the `Dictinary.GetEnumerator()` that returns an enumerator.

Answer (score 1):

You could return `_dict.getEnumerator()` but it would produce KeyValuePair items. You might as well return an `IDictionary`.

So you probably want `_dict.Keys.getEnumerator()`, and/or the same for the Values.

But returning an enumerator is odd, much better to return: `_dict.Keys as IEnumerable<KeyType>`

Answer (score 1):

To iterate over the dictionary you can use:

`Dictionary.GetEnumerator` that returns KeyValuePairs.

`Dictionary.Keys` that returns a KeyCollection.

`Dictionary.Values` that returns a ValueCollection.

If you for some reason need to hide the dictionary, you can cast Dictionary.Keys and Dictionary.Values to Array/List whatever you want.